Looker Studio: Calculate total sum of a column and show it in every row
Calculate total sum of a column and show it in every row
Hi, I have this table



ID
Quantity




1
10


2
20


3
30



I need to calculate the total of "Quantity" column in order to have this new column:



ID
Quantity
Total Quantity




1
10
60


2
20
60


3
30
60



I need this "Total Quantity" column as a calculated field, in order to use it as denominator in other calculated fields.
Thanks in advance!
I am not quite sure how to go about this..

https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/6299685 must help you. Or that https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7569890.
At right side menu open Data -> "Add a field" in your current table -> "Add calculated field" -> fill formula field like "sum(quantity)" and fill "Field Name"-> Done
